# Using If statement with shell commands in jenkins Declarative pipeline cloudformation

Tags: shell, if-statement, jenkins, aws-cloudformation, multibranch-pipeline

I am integrating aws cloudformation into my jenkins pipeline. I want execute a

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name dev-nics-proxyservlet-svc --region us-west-2
```

command to see if I have a stack out there with the name I am looking for. If the command finds that the stack exists, I want to delete the stack:

```
$ aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name dev-nics-proxyservlet-svc
```

But if the stack doesnt exists, I want to create the stack:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name dev-nics-proxyservlet-svc --region us-west-2 --template-body file://dev-nics-proxyservlet-cluster.yml --parameters file://dev-nics-proxyservlet-svc-param.json --capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM" "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
```

How can I can write this shell comman in a declarative multibranch jenkins pipeline? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: This should in in `bash`?

Comment: I think so? not sure if there is a way to do it in groovy

Comment: Ok. You can check my answer in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something along these lines should work:

```
if aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name dev-nics-proxyservlet-svc --region us-west-2 &>/dev/null 
then
    aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name dev-nics-proxyservlet-svc
else
    aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name dev-nics-proxyservlet-svc --region us-west-2 --template-body file://dev-nics-proxyservlet-cluster.yml --parameters file://dev-nics-proxyservlet-svc-param.json --capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM" "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
fi
```

The `if` works by checiking **exit code** of `aws cloudformation describe-stacks`. If its 0, then stack exists, if not 0, then it does not exist.

Comment: THANK YOU! quick question how does forwarding the response to &>/dev/null give me an exit code?